# How to export mysql database based on a where condition

Tags: mysql, export, phpmyadmin, condition

I need to export the data and structure of a table but the data must have a specific condition (WHERE status=0 and id>20).

How to export mysql database based on a where condition from phpMyAdmin or anything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using SQL from the mysql command-line:

```
SELECT * from YOURTABLE
WHERE status=0 and id>20
INTO OUTFILE 'yourtable.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

or using mysqldump with the --where= option:

```
mysqldump -u youruser -p yourdbname yourtablename --where="status=0 and id>20">yourtable.sql
```

Using phpMyAdmin you can execute the query in the GUI & click "export" under the resultset.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `from table_name ....`  before `INTO OUTFILE` gives an error(`Unexpected ordering of clauses. (near "FROM" at position 10)`).

What works for me.

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE '/Volumes/Development/sql/sql/enabled_contacts.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name = 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

- **Solution 1**: use mysqldump from command line

```
mysqldump --no-create-db --no-create-info --complete-insert \
          -u<yourUsername> -p<yourPassword>  -h<yourDbHost>  -P<yourDbPort> \
          <yourDatabaseName>  <yourTableName>  --where="status=0 and id>20"
```

Please be aware of that  by default mysqldump will try to lock the table first, so in case you meet an error about lacking of privilege for locking table, probably you need `--single-transaction` also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104612/run-mysqldump-without-locking-tables for not locking table for different db engines.

- **Solution 2**: use a GUI client tool.

For example in **MySQL Workbench**, you can run the select and export the query result to a csv file.
[image]